# Resolving executable user stack trace addresses in ftrace

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging, trace

I'm trying to obtain a user stack trace in `ftrace`, but for some reason, only my user program cannot resolve the addresses to symbols. First, the OS I'm using is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mypc 2.6.38-16-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 6 18:00:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

The (trivial) user-space program I'm using, `wtest.c`, is included below. I compile it with:

```
gcc -g -pg -O0 wtest.c -o wtest
```

... hoping that `-g` and `-pg` will include enough debugging symbol information.

Then, I run the `wtest` program under `ftrace`. Note that the I want to obtain the user space stacktrace as a sort of a guide where in my user space program I am currently, while I otherwise run the `function` tracer. The [Linux/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt?v=2.6.38) isn't explicit about this, but in order to have a stack trace, there *must* be something to trigger it - and just the `function` (or `function_graph`) tracer, on its own, will not do any such triggering. So I choose to trigger anytime a system call is detected via `events/raw_syscalls`. Furthermore, the stack trace will print addresses only, unless `sym-userobj` is specified. So, I run this script to do the tracing:

```
sudo bash -c '
KDBGPATH="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing"
echo 1 > $KDBGPATH/events/raw_syscalls/enable
echo userstacktrace > $KDBGPATH/trace_options
echo sym-userobj > $KDBGPATH/trace_options
echo function > $KDBGPATH/current_tracer ;
echo 0 > $KDBGPATH/tracing_on
echo > $KDBGPATH/trace
echo 1 > $KDBGPATH/tracing_on ; /media/disk/wtest ; echo 0 > $KDBGPATH/tracing_on
cat $KDBGPATH/trace > wtest.ftrace
'
```

However, the trace ends up containing something like this:

```
...
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413238: arch_flush_lazy_mmu_mode <-__kunmap_atomic
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413239: syscall_trace_leave <-syscall_exit_work
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413240: up_read <-do_page_fault
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413241: sys_exit: NR 54 = 0
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: <user stack trace>
 =>  <008f9416>
 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0[+0x4f49]
 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0[+0x5cc3]
 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0[+0x13a3]
 => /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so[+0xec58]
 => /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so[+0x2957a]
 => /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so[+0x2d403]
 => /usr/bin/Xorg[+0xdefc8]
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: save_stack_trace_user <-ftrace_trace_userstack
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
            Xorg-1136  [001] 16246.413242: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413242: syscall_trace_leave <-syscall_exit_work
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413243: sys_exit: NR 120 = 0
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: <user stack trace>
 =>  <00222416>
 =>  <08086a69>
 =>  <080753e0>
 =>  <080783b5>
 =>  <08073c09>
 =>  <08077c93>
 =>  <08078374>
 =>  <08073c09>
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: save_stack_trace_user <-ftrace_trace_userstack
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413245: __copy_from_user_ll_nozero <-save_stack_trace_user
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413260: down_read_trylock <-do_page_fault
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413262: _cond_resched <-do_page_fault
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413263: find_vma <-do_page_fault
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413265: handle_mm_fault <-do_page_fault
           wtest-16108 [000] 16246.413266: __kmap_atomic <-handle_mm_fault
...
```

In other words - `Xorg` has its user stack trace resolved fine (at least in the `.so` libraries) - and pretty much all other processes ending up in the `ftrace` log (like `bash`, etc); however, the user stack trace for `wtest` is printed with addresses only ?! I explicitly called the executable through its absolute path, but that doesn't seem to make much difference.

Is there a way I could compile my `wtest` program, so its user stack trace gets its symbols resolved - or does the problem lie elsewhere? (I have tried `-ggdb` and `-gdwarf-2` instead of `-g`, but those don't really help here...)

Here is the code for `wtest.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  // O_CREAT, O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR

int main(void) {
  char filename[] = "/tmp/wtest.txt";
  char buffer[] = "abcd";
  int fd;
  mode_t perms = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH;

  fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, perms);
  write(fd,buffer,4);
  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-g` switch is what will enable `gcc` to compile your code with debugging symbols enabled. If you're not seeing any symbols then the issue is likely a library that you're compiling against, which does not provide a version of the library with symbols enabled.

See this SO Q&A: titled: [How Does The Debugging Option -g Change the Binary Executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89603/how-does-the-debugging-option-g-change-the-binary-executable). This SO Q&A also makes mention of debugging symbols vs. linker symbols, titled: [Why does gcc add symbols to non-debug build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491158/why-does-gcc-add-symbols-to-non-debug-build).

If you want the debugging symbols for a particular package/library they're typically called `<package name>-dbg` or `<package name>-dbgsym` on Ubuntu. This article discussed it in further details, titled: [DebuggingProgramCrash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash#Debug_Symbol_Packages).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @slm - could this also refer to the `libc` library? As I don't see what other library would the program above refer to... Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau - Possibly do you happen to know if you have `-dbg` or `-dbgsym` packages loaded? You might need those for what you want. See updates.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, @slm - I definitely do not have `-dbg` packages loaded; which is why I find this strange - if they were the problem, then I shouldn't get any resolved traces from `Xorg` or other processes? And this trace only gives an offset into an executable file, so the debug info (as in, a link to source code file and line number) isn't even needed... Yet, I get stacktraces resolved everywhere, except my program; and the program isn't even linked to anything other than (implicitly) `libc`?